# EF Core 6, creates new parent record when trying to create only child record

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

Here are my models:

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
    public CartHeader CartHeader { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CartDetails> CartDetails { get; set; }
}

public class CartHeader
{
    [Key]
    public int CartHeaderId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string? CouponCode { get; set; }
}

public class CartDetails
{
    public int CartDetailsID { get; set; }
    public int CartHeaderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CartHeaderId")]
    public virtual CartHeader CartHeader { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code which populates the `CartHeader` and `CartDetails` tables:

```
var cartHeaderFromDb = await _dbContext.CartHeaders.AsNoTracking()
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserId == shoppingCart.CartHeader.UserId);

if (cartHeaderFromDb == null)
{
    //create header and details
    /// This creates CartHeader and CartDetails Records
    _dbContext.CartDetails.Add(shoppingCart.CartDetails.FirstOrDefault());
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
else
{
    //if header is not null
    //check if details has same product
    /// This block should only creates CartDetails and not create CartHeader, but it does
    var cartDetailsFromDb = _dbContext.CartDetails.AsNoTracking().Where(u =>
        u.CartHeaderId == cartHeaderFromDb.CartHeaderId).ToList();

    if (!cartDetailsFromDb.Exists(c => c.ProductId == shoppingCart.CartDetails.First().ProductId))
    {
        //create details                       
        shoppingCart.CartHeader = null;
        shoppingCart.CartDetails.FirstOrDefault().CartHeaderId = cartHeaderFromDb.CartHeaderId;
        _dbContext.CartDetails.Add(shoppingCart.CartDetails.FirstOrDefault());
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        //update the count / cart details
        shoppingCart.CartHeader = null;
        shoppingCart.CartDetails.FirstOrDefault().CartHeaderId = cartHeaderFromDb.CartHeaderId;
        shoppingCart.CartDetails.FirstOrDefault().Count += cartDetailsFromDb.Count;
        _dbContext.CartDetails.Update(shoppingCart.CartDetails.FirstOrDefault());
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Here both `if` and `else` blocks create another `CartHeader` record which I don't want. I want to use the same CartHeader ID, if there exists one. Tried `AsNoTracking()` at various places and setting navigation properties to `null` as well, no success! It always creates another `CartHeader` record and the new `CartDetails` gets that new CartHeader ID. I cannot figure out what I am missing here.

Comment: ```_dbContext.Entry(shoppingCart.CartHeader).State = EntityState.Unchanged;``` This line is also not making any difference. It still creates new CartHeader record.

Comment: Take a look at this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing the same problem, I was able to resolve the issue using the following code.

```
_dbContext.CartDetails.Add(new CartDetails()
{
    CartHeaderId = cartHeaderFromDb.CartHeaderId,
    ProductId = shoppingCart.CartDetails.First().ProductId,
    Count = shoppingCart.CartDetails.First().Count
}
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

With this code, no new CartHeader records are being created.

Comments are welcome to improve it. Thanks